# Application specs are slow when upgrading to ruby 3.2.2 and 3.3.0 from 3.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-3.1

I am in the process of upgrading ruby version from v3.1.4 to v3.2.2
The specs take 18-19 minutes on v3.1.4, but they run for about 45-47 minutes v3.2.2

This is one of the logs i see in test.log when running rspecs for ruby 3.1.4

```
User Create (1.7ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "role", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at")
```

Where as in ruby 3.2.2 and 3.3.0

```
User Create (8.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "role", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at")
```

Any idea what i might be missing during the upgrades. I have done many upgrades before, but this one is different.

Comment: The logs you show are the SQL queries, which are not executed in Ruby but within your database server. If your SQL queries take longer than before, the cause is very likely to be found within your database server, not Ruby.

Comment: If you go back to the older version is it still giving similar results? What about Ruby 3.2.3 or 3.3.0? I'd expect 3.2 to be faster, but there could be external variables here that are impacting your results.

Comment: One thing to consider: If you're on an NVMe/SSD type drive and it's getting really full, something all too common when your Rails `log/` dir gets totally out of control, a nearly full drive (90%+ space used) will perform **very** badly.

Comment: same thing on ruby 3.2.3 and 3.3.0. if i go back to 3.1.4 its fast again.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit gem. It was Bigdecimal gem. Until bigdecimal gem v3.1.1, it was good. They changed something in v3.1.2 which started slowing. Anyways, i am unblocked and good with the upgrade. Thanks everyone for taking time to answer the question.